# PHP/MySQL pagination going wrong

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Using PHP on my website linking to a library database in MySQL. The one area I can't seem to get right is the pagination of results. I've tried about twenty different code snippets and have the same problem each time - can't get more than the first page of results to display. Despite reading lots of forum posts on this one, can't get past it. My select query is slightly more complex in that several keywords can be combined and it is searching multiple fields. When results are displayed, they also pull data from different tables. I really hope someone can spot where I'm going wrong. Switch statement used dependent on which type of search the user requests, so the code for one case given below.

```
$term = trim($_REQUEST['term']);
$searchterm = mysql_real_escape_string($term, $link);
$index = $_REQUEST['index'];
switch ($index)
{
     case "title":
     $array = explode(" ", $searchterm); 
     $sql = "select identifier, title, publication_date from publication where";
     foreach ($array as $key => $keyword) { 
 $sql .= " (title like '%$keyword%' or alternative_title like '%$keyword%')"; 
 if ($key != (sizeof($array) - 1)) $sql .= " and "; 
 if ($key == (sizeof($array) - 1)) $sql .= " order by title"; 
     }
     if(!$result = mysql_query($sql, $link)) { 
 showerror();
}
else {
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 if ($numrows == 0) {
  echo "<h2>No records found</h2>";
}
//start pagination
$perPage = 10; 
$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) ? (int)$_REQUEST['page'] : 1; 
$startAt = $perPage * ($page - 1);  
$totalPages = ceil($numrows / $perPage);
$links = ""; 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {   
  $links .= ($i != $page ) ? "&nbsp;<a href='search.php?page=$i&search=$term'>
Page $i</a> " : "$page "; 
}   
echo "<h3>Displaying page $page of $totalPages:</h3><br />";
$counter = 1;
$sql = "select identifier, title, publication_date from publication where";
foreach ($array as $key => $keyword) { 
  $sql .= " (title like '%$keyword%' or alternative_title like '%$keyword%')"; 
  if ($key != (sizeof($array) - 1)) $sql .= " and "; 
  if ($key == (sizeof($array) - 1)) $sql .= " order by title 
LIMIT $startAt, $perPage"; 
}
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
echo "<table class=\"results\">\n"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  //echo data
}
echo "</table><br />\n";
echo $links; // show links to other pages
echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
   }
break;
```

Comment: "I've tried about twenty different code snippets" --- what about writing *your own code* (that is what programmers generally do).

Comment: You can only write your own code if you know what the solution to the problem is, I wouldn't need to ask for help if I could see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Chelle: you did ask about how to fix some of those snippets. But if you wrote your own code - you would ask some **specific** question instead. "You can only write your own code if you know what the solution to the problem is" --- wrong. Decompose the task to a lot of smaller subtasks and solve them one by one, step by step.

Comment: @zerkms: Breaking it down its clear the calculations are working correctly in that 3 pages are being returned for a result set of 24. Hovering on the link shows the right information is in the URL for page number and search term. But the problem remains that the search does not seem to run again to produce the data required for the remaining pages. And this is something I obviously don't have the experience to solve.

Comment: `can't get more than the first page of results to display`: Can you expand your explanation of this issue? Does it work when you remove or increase the `LIMIT`? FWIW this is a huge chunk of code for folks to read and it's not all necessary, you'll get better answers by isolating the problem.

Comment: @Wesley: Apologies for putting the full code, but I'd tried previously using only the pagination code and wasn't able to isolate the problem so thought I'd be more explicit this time in case it was my query that was throwing it off

Answer (score 0):

as stated above, -1 vote for placing someone elses code instead of trying it yourself. This code is wayyyy to much for what a pagination script should do. You could have added more specific code snippet and a better question. I'll try to take a look at it however.

As you can't get further than page 1 it seems that somethings going wrong aroung `$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) ? (int)$_REQUEST['page'] : 1 ;` or a little below. Try `echoëing` your SQL code for each page and take a look if the LIMIT is right or that it stays the same, probably the last. At least that gives you a starting point from where to take a look in your code.

Does it give you the right amount of links to go to?

Comment: Yes, always provides the right number of links, I can change the number of records to display per page for limit and it works OK, and it echoes that it has set $page to 1 OK for the first page. Any additional pages are always blank.

Comment: if it gives the right amount of pages you might want to check your SQL Query that is meant to fetch the right amount of rows. Most likely when you get a blank page this means you get an empty resultset from the query, which can mean two things: (1) the amount of pages displayed is incorrect (but I guess you're testing with a decent amount of data in the table) or the query is not right. So first thing I would do (`echo $sql;`)

Comment: thanks for your help, realised now where the problem was. I'd passed the search term into the URL for the query to use on the subsequent pages, but I hadn't passed the value for the type of search to carry out so the case statement couldn't execute

Comment: Good to hear, good luck with the progress of your script/page.